# Why Won't This Python Code match the Formula for a European Call Option?

Tags: python

```
import math
import numpy as np



S0 = 100.; K = 100.; T = 1.0; r = 0.05; sigma = 0.2
M = 100; dt = T / M; I = 500000

S = np.zeros((M + 1, I))
S[0] = S0
for t in range(1, M + 1):
    z = np.random.standard_normal(I)
    S[t] = S[t - 1] * np.exp((r - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * dt + sigma * 
    math.sqrt(dt) * z)

C0 = math.exp(-r * T) * np.sum(np.maximum(S[-1] - K, 0)) / I

print ("European Option Value is ", C0)
```

It gives a value of around 10.45 as you increase the number of simulations, but using the B-S formula the value should be around 10.09. Anybody know why the code isn't giving a number closer to the formula?

Comment: How many simulations have you run to get 10.45?

Comment: Try `C0 - 0.36` at the end.

Comment: This is with 500000 simulations so that's not it.